# multiple active buttons in jquery mobile nav bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have needs 3 buttons with every data posted.
1. like 2. comment 3. share.
now when user clicks on any of the button the process is done with ajax.
The problem is if user have click like and after that on comment and share. The like button is unactivated. What i do so like button remain active if user click or tap on other buttons.
I can choose other navigation bars of this style if available and works according to me.
By the way i have to applie this in mobile version of http://www.funnenjoy.com/m

I have also designed a jsfiddle [`link to js fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ravinderpayal/PeS2D/1050/)

Comment: Please post code and maybe a jsfiddle(jsfiddle.com). I can't even see the buttons you're talking about in your link.

Comment: this [link](http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox) will serve your purpose

Comment: yah its some similar what i want. can increase its size and add icons and how can i make links with them. And main requirement how can i make active by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have find this i use privent.fefault and it works for me.
my code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('.comment').click(function(){
                        ajax_loader(this);
                        return false;
});
});
function ajax_loader(el){
event.preventDefault();
var url=$(el).attr('href');
$.get(url);
   alert(url);
   return false;}
```

and for like button

```
    $(document).ready(function(){$('.like').click(function(){
                        ajax_loader(this);
                        return false;
});
});
function ajax_loader(el){
var url=$(el).attr('href');
$.get(url);
   alert(url);
   return false;}
```

and this one for share button

```
    $(document).ready(function(){$('.comment').click(function(){
                        ajax_loader(this);
                        return false;
});
});
function ajax_loader(el){
event.preventDefault();
var url=$(el).attr('href');
$.get(url);
   alert(url);
   return false;}
```

i have applied this in my social networking website http://www.funnenjoy.com